# Get the event data in manually bind events in full calender

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar in that I need to handle both *click* and *dblclick* event on eventclick.
For that I did the following code.

Taking data from server and from json data :

```
   function FormJosn(Data) {
            var Json = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) {
                Json.push({
                    "id": Data[i].Appointment_ID,
                    "title": Data[i].F_Name + ' ' + Data[i].L_Name,
                    'start': Data[i].start,
                    'end': Data[i].End,
                    'allDay': false
                });
            }
            Calander(Json);
        }
```

and render full calender,

```
function Calander(Data) {
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            editable: true,
            droppable: true,
            drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

                // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

                // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

                // assign it the date that was reported
                copiedEventObject.start = date;
                copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

                // render the event on the calendar
                // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

                // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                    // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                    $(this).remove();
                }

            },
            select: function (start, end, allDay) {

                SetAppointmentBookingDateTime(start);
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
            editable: false,
            disableResizing:false,
            events: Data,

            eventRender: function (event, element)
            {
                element.bind('click', function (event, element) {

                    var doubleClickOpportunity = 200, // Adjust this to whatever feels right
                        $elem = $(event.target),
                        clicker = $elem.data('clicker'); // Holder for the doubleclick setTimeout

                    if (clicker) {
                        // If there's a setTimeout stored in clicker, then this is a double click
                        clearTimeout(clicker);
                        $elem.data('clicker', '');
                        $elem.trigger('doubleclick');
                    } else {
                        $elem.data('clicker', setTimeout(function () {
                            $elem.data('clicker', '');
                            $elem.trigger('singleclick');
                        }, doubleClickOpportunity));
                    }

                });

                element.bind('singleclick', function (event, element) {
                    // I'm a single click!
                    window.location = "http://" + window.location.host + "/Hospital/Treatment/AddTreatment/" + event.id;
                });

                element.bind('doubleclick', function () {
                    // I'm a double click!
                    $(".Modify-Appointment").modal("show");
                });

            }
        });
    }
```

I have bind `click` and `dblclick` eventRender which will working fine but I am not getting data of the event as it get it on `eventClick` function.

I need those data to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass data to jQuery's callback, as per the [bind documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), you should use the following signature:

```
.bind( eventType [, eventData ], handler )
```

So you must pass an object to the callback, like this:

```
element.bind('singleclick', { event: event, element: element }, function () {
    // I'm a single click!
    window.location = "http://" + window.location.host + "/Hospital/Treatment/AddTreatment/" + event.id;
});
```

Also note that as of jQuery 1.7, [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is the preferred method over `.bind()`